# Background Video in HTML5 not scaling

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get a video to scale with the browser window, and still cover the whole area, but cannot achieve this.  Any one know why my current method isn't working?

HTML:

```
<div class="bgVideoWrap">
<video id="bgVideo" loop="true" autoplay="true" >
    <source src="video/bgVideos/Speak_BG.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
</video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bgVideo {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.bgVideoWrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

html, body  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using background:cover; ?

Comment: also investigate this http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

Comment: background-size:100% will also work

Comment: Well, the problem is that its not technically a background.  Its a video that's pretending to be a background, so it won;t be effected by the CSS background property.

Answer (score 1):

## [*-DEMO-*](http://jsfiddle.net/ASYqv/2/)

Set `background-size: cover;` to `.bgVideoWrap`and `opacity: 0.6;` to `#bgVideo`

MARKUP:

```
<div class=bgVideoWrap>
<video id=bgVideo loop autoplay poster=http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/poster.png>
    <source src=http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4 type=video/mp4>
    <source src=http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv type=video/ogg>
     <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
</div>
```

STYLE:

```
html, body  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
}

#bgVideo {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0.6;    /*Set opacity*/
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.bgVideoWrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333 url("http://aimg.disneystore.com/content/ds/skyway/2012/category/full/cp_FWB_Brave_20120926.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works for an image, but fails to work for the video inside of the .bgVideoWrap element.

Comment: check the update it works and add attr `poster` to your video

Comment: This is helpful, but I cannot get it to function on my site, even having copy and pasting the code.  There must be an error somewhere else.  That is what I am looking for in the jsfiddle though.

Comment: Can you post the link to your website please maybe you have something overwriting the video style

Comment: http://alpha.oddmachine.com/work.php  Is the page I'm having trouble with.  Nevermind the "Bodum" thing.

Comment: just remove `min-width` and `min-height` from `#bgVideo` and set `height: 100%;`and
`width: 100%;`  end result would be `#bgVideo {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Right, but then It doesn't cover the entire background anymore.  I'll figure it out sooner or later though.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56302/discussion-between-kougiland-and-zac-ledyard).